# Implementing a custom log4net PatternLayout

Tags: log4net-configuration, log4net-appender

I need log4net to produce a CSV file and have uncovered [this article that implements one](http://element533.blogspot.com/2010/05/writing-to-csv-using-log4net.html). My problem is how to integrate that code to my web project. A straight-up copy paste leaves ReSharper insisting that the namespace be changed from '**CsvLogging**' to '**MyApp.Web**' which makes sense in that now, the web project's assembly now has a class named '**CsvLogging**'.

But log4net is not happy and tosses the error pasted below.

My appender's config looks like:

```
<layout type=" MyApp.Web.CsvLogging.CsvPatternLayout, MyApp.Web.CsvLogging">
```

...which from my reading of [this article on how to reference a custom pattern](https://dejanfajfar.wordpress.com/2011/04/14/log4net-custom-layoutpattern/) , should be correct.

```
log4net:ERROR Failed to find type [ MyApp.Web.CsvLogging.CsvPatternLayout, MyApp.Web.CsvLogging]
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'MyApp.Web.CsvLogging' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'MyApp.Web.CsvLogging'
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMarkHandle stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName, ObjectHandleOnStack type)
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName)
   at System.RuntimeType.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Type.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase)
   at log4net.Util.SystemInfo.GetTypeFromString(Assembly relativeAssembly, String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase)
   at log4net.Util.SystemInfo.GetTypeFromString(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase)
   at log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.XmlHierarchyConfigurator.CreateObjectFromXml(XmlElement element, Type defaultTargetType, Type typeConstraint)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a class named `MyApp.Web.CsvLogging`, but your assembly is still named `MyApp.Web`
Try the following:

```
<layout type=" MyApp.Web.CsvLogging.CsvPatternLayout, MyApp.Web">
```

Basically .net naming for assemblies is `"namespace.class, assembly"`

Comment: Which <b>was</b> one of the permutations I'd tried. Figured it failed like other attempts because i was trusting the Size and TimeStamp of my filesystem. After clicking refresh - I still was looking at an older date and 0 size. Until i actually opened to find joyfully expected content. [sigh]

Comment: Well, sometimes all you need is a bit of rubberducking; glad this helped :)